# EasyMock's niceMock equivalent for RhinoMocks

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks, easymock

The EasyMock framework (mocks for Java) has very clever method **createNiceMock**, it is:

*Creates a mock object that implements the given interface, order checking is disabled by default, and the mock object will return 0, null or false for unexpected invocations.*

I wonder about some equivalent method in Rhino Mocks framework that can mocks with **0, null or false** for unexpected invocations (I am not interesting in *order checking* but if it will be it will OK too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are characteristics of [*dynamic mock*](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Introduction.ashx):

> **Dynamic Mock** - Loose replay semantics. Created by calling DynamicMock()
>
> **Loose replay semantics**: All method calls during the replay state are accepted. If there is no special handling setup for a given method, a null or zero is returned. All of the expected methods must be called for the object to pass verification.

In earlier versions of you had to explicitly create one:

```
var mocks = new MockRepository();
var service = mocks.DynamicMock<IService>();
```

Nowadays, by default mocks are assumed to be dynamic mocks as long as you create them with  `MockRepository.GenerateMock<T>()` method. Expectations call order is also **irrelevant**. Assuming we got expectations set up as below:

```
var dependency = MocksRepository.GenerateMock<IDependency>();
dependency.Expect(d => d.SecondMethod());
dependency.Expect(d => d.FirstMethod());
```

Tested code like the example below

```
public void DoWork()
{
    this.Dependency.FirstMethod();
    this.Dependency.SecondMethod();
    this.Dependency.ThirdMethod();
}
```

won't cause the test to fail. Order doesn't matter, unexpected invocations are ignored and return default values.